# Things to consider before including a js library in large existing project

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, crm

I am working on a large project which is a derivative of XRMS CRM. Unfortunately the previous developer did not properly (or even improperly) document his/her coding. Now I have a large piece of messy PHP + JS files. Currectly it doesn't use any js library and uses native JS codes. For some reasons I want to utilize jQuery, prototype or mootools. As I did some tests with including jQuery in some pages, I realized they were working fine. But since there are just too many pages, it will be extremely tedious to test all functionalities on all pages.

I want to know key points that I should consider before I apply any of these js libraries.

Comment: I would re-code all from zero, if its possible.

Comment: I would do the same. Its just damn impossible :(

Comment: What do you mean by key points? What exactly are you looking for? It'd be good if you could start by giving an example.

Comment: Adding the jQuery library to a page will do **nothing** until you start rewriting the code to use the `$` (or alternate) accessor for things.

Comment: @Sukumar I mean the key possibilities where jQuery will conflict with existing JS code.

Comment: Any particular reason why this question is marked as non-constructive?! Also, when you downvote at least mention the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a library like jQuery, the entire codebase is contained within the scope of a single variable, deliberately to avoid conflicts with existing code.

In the case of jQuery, it is the dollar symbol (`$`), though this can be overridden to use the `jQuery` variable is `$` is in use elsewhere (called noconflict mode).

This means that as long as your existing code doesn't use the `$` variable, you can safely include the library without fear of it treading all over your existing code.

Comment: Thnks for the answer. Are you 100% sure that no $ variable in existing code means no conflict with jQuery? Any reference that I can provide to others, please.

Comment: Without getting too technical, you can be sure by looking at the jQuery code itself, the entire library is contained within a set of brackets (to create a local scope), and the very last line: `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;` shows you that `$` and `jQuery` are the only to variable names to escape from that scope. If you use neither of those, you are good to go.

Comment: Also, if you are unsure about the safety of the `$` variable in your existing codebase, it may be best to invoke `jQuery.noConflict()` immediately after including the library, and stick to using the `jQuery` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Consider including jQuery in a [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) manner, implementing [graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system). If something went wrong the user would still be able to use the site.

Putting jQuery on the bottom of the page will help with page loading speed and may avoid some of the potential conflicts.

See also [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode and [Using jQuery with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Writing the new code write also the unit tests (e.g. using [qunit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit) or [jstestdriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/), include the unit tests for the legacy code whether it is possible. This helps a lot when [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

Comment: Can you please explain a little more what you mean by "...progressive enhancement manner, implementing graceful degradation"?

Comment: @Muhammad I've added some helpful links.